# jQuery fadIn displays div at bottom of page in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, lightbox, fadein

I have some code to debug which is creating a lightbox manually:

```
$('.contact').click(function () {

            $('html').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');

            $('<div class="overlay"></div>')
                .css('top', $(document).scrollTop())
                .css('opacity', '0')
                .animate({ 'opacity': '0.5' }, 0)
                .appendTo('body');

            $('<div class="lightbox"></div>')
                .hide()
                .appendTo('body');

$('.lightbox').load(function () {
            showRecaptcha('recaptcha_div');
        });
        var top = ($(window).height() - $('.lightbox').height()) / 2;
        var left = ($(window).width() - $('.lightbox').width()) / 2;
        $('.lightbox').css({
            'top': top + $(document).scrollTop(),
            'left': left,
            'zIndex':'2000'
        }).fadeIn(0);

        return false;
    });
```

The lightbox currently appears offscreen, if you zoom out of the page you can see it sitting way out in the bottom left corner.

If I change `fadeIn(0)` to `show()` then the lightbox appears in the correct place.

Has anyone else had similar issues to this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in IE when trying to set top and left positions with the jQuery offset function. I fixed it by running this first to ensure it starts at top left:

```
$(".lightbox").offset({top: 0, left: 0});
```

Also make sure it is `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;` and you have typo'd `fadeIn(0)` in your snippet.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Good to know that someone else was having similar problems. Resetting the offset unfortunately did not work for me this time.

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the functions, so make it fadeIn first and then set the css? If this works you could do a hack where you show() then set css then hide() then fadeIn, the show/hide won't be noticeable.

Comment: Also one more thing to try, maybe rename your top and left variables in case they're causing an issue.